# Direct mapped cache example

Tags: caching, assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

i am really confused on the topic Direct Mapped Cache i've been looking around for an example with a good explanation and it's making me more confused then ever.

For example: I have

- 2048 byte memory
- 64 byte big cache
- 8 byte cache lines
  with direct mapped cache how do i determine the 'LINE' 'TAG' and "Byte offset'?

  ---
- i believe that the total number of addressing bits is 11 bits because 2048 = 2^11
- 2048/64 = 2^5 = 32 blocks (0 to 31) (5bits needed)  (tag)
- 64/8 = 8 = 2^3 = 3 bits for the index
- 8 byte cache lines = 2^3 which means i need 3 bits for the byte offset

so the addres would be like this: 5 for the tag, 3 for the index and 3 for the byte offset

Do i have this figured out correctly?

Comment: Yes. Though, I found more logical to get the length of the tag as the difference between the address width (11 bits) and the index+offset bits (3+3): 11-6 = 5. Of course, both methods are equivalents.

Comment: I also recommend the method proposed by @MargaretBloom, because it works for non-direct mapped caches too. If in this example you had the same 8 lines in 4 sets, the number of tag bits would be 6 (11 - 3 - 2), and not 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do i figured out correctly? **YES**

Explanation

1) Main memmory size is 2048 bytes = 2<sup>11</sup>. So you need 11 bits to address a byte (If your word size is 1 byte) [word = smallest individual unit that will be accessed with the address]

2) You can calculating tag bits in direct mapping by doing (main memmory size / cash size). But i will explain a little more about tag bits.

Here the size of a cashe line( which is always same as size of a main memmory block) is 8 bytes. which is 2<sup>3</sup> bytes. So you need 3 bits to represent a byte within a cashe line. Now you have 8 bits (11 - 3) are remaining in the address.

Now the total number of lines present in the cache is (cashe size / line size) =   2<sup>6</sup> / 2<sup>3</sup>  = 2<sup>3</sup>

So, you have 3 bits to represent the line in which the your required byte is present.

The number of remaining bits now are 5 (8 - 3).

These 5 bits can be used to represent a tag. :)

3) 3 bit for index. If you were trying to label the number of bits needed to represent a line as index. Yes you are right.

4) 3 bits will be used to access a byte withing a cache line. (8 = 2<sup>3</sup>)

So,

*11 bits total address length = 5 tag bits + 3 bits to represent a line + 3 bits to represent a byte(word) withing a line*

Hope there is no confusion now.